# how create correct sql to get only one record with relations?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

built_structures:

```
id | location_id | structure_id
1  | 1           | 1
2  | 1           | 2
3  | 2           | 1
```

ongoing_structures:

```
id | built_structure_id
1  | 1
2  | 1
```

Now I need get all data from `ongoing_structures` where `built_structures.location_id = 1` so I expect record `id = 1` from `ongoing_structures` but I have 2 records `id` 1 and 2 from `built_structures`

```sql
SELECT * FROM ongoing_structures os
JOIN built_structures bs ON (os.built_structure_id = bs.id)
WHERE bs.location_id = 1
```

How can I get records from ongoing depends from location ?

### Update

My mistake thank you for help. Table should be like this

ongoing_structures

```
id | built_structure_id
1  | 1
2  | 3
```

Comment: Both `ongoing_structures` rows  refer to `built_structures` rows with `location_id = 1` (both to the same entry in fact). So why do you expect only one of the rows and not both? Do you have some additional rule in mind you forgot to tell us?

Comment: So you suggest i should get all structure from built_strutures where locations_id = 1 and join table ongoing_structures where bs.id = on.built_strutures_id. but must be some way to do this from ongoing table

Comment: I am not suggesting anything. I wonder why you are considering getting two result rows an issue. Maybe you are just confused with your data. The `ongoing_structures` row with `id = 1` has `built_structure_id = 1` and thus refers to  `built_structures` row with `id = 1` the location of which is 1. A match. The `ongoing_structures` row with `id = 2` has `built_structure_id = 1`, too, and thus also refers to  `built_structures` row with `id = 1` the location of which is 1 as mentioned. Another match.

Comment: @Wraith, I think your problem is the keys. Have you tried os.id = bs.id?

Comment: @JoPapou13: These are IDs of two different tables. They must have nothing to do with each other. Why would you even compare them?

Comment: thnak YOU. I am so stupid. In table ongoing_structures record id = 2 should has built_structure_id = 3

Comment: You're welcome :-) If you want data from one table and only look up data in another, you don't have to join by the way. E.g.: `select * from ongoing_structures where built_structure_id in (select id from built_structures where location_id = 1)`.

Comment: ooo much easier, thx